# Measuring execution time when using threads

Tags: c++, multithreading, time, measure

I would like to measure the execution time of some code. The code starts in the main() function and finishes in an event handler.

I have a C++11 code that looks like this:

```
#include <iostream>

#include <time.h>

...

volatile clock_t t;

void EventHandler()
{
    // when this function called is the end of the part that I want to measure
    t = clock() - t;
    std::cout << "time in seconds: " << ((float)t)/CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
}

int main()
{
    MyClass* instance = new MyClass(EventHandler); // this function starts a new std::thread
    instance->start(...); // this function only passes some data to the thread working data, later the thread will call EventHandler()
    t = clock();
    return 0;
}
```

So it is guaranteed that the EventHandler() will be called only once, and only after an instance->start() call.

It is working, this code give me some output, but it is a horrible code, it uses global variable and different threads access global variable. However I can't change the used API (the constructor, the way the thread calls to EventHandler).

I would like to ask if a better solution exists.

Thank you.

Comment: FYI: volatile is not atomic<>, if this works at all, it's basically luck.

Comment: There's a race problem here. If the worker thread is fast enough, `EventHandler` could get called before `t` is first initialized... You'd better not attempt cross-thread time measurement. It's just random.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Global variable is unavoidable, as long as `MyClass` expects a plain function and there's no way to pass some context pointer along with the function...

You could write the code in a slightly more tidy way, though:

```
#include <future>
#include <thread>
#include <chrono>
#include <iostream>

struct MyClass
{
    typedef void (CallbackFunc)();

    constexpr explicit MyClass(CallbackFunc* handler)
     : m_handler(handler)
    {
    }

    void Start()
    {
        std::thread(&MyClass::ThreadFunc, this).detach();
    }

private:
    void ThreadFunc()
    {
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(5));
        m_handler();
    }

    CallbackFunc*     m_handler;
};


std::promise<std::chrono::time_point<std::chrono::high_resolution_clock>>   gEndTime;

void EventHandler()
{
    gEndTime.set_value(std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now());
}


int main()
{
    MyClass         task(EventHandler);

    auto            trigger = gEndTime.get_future();
    auto            startTime = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    task.Start();
    trigger.wait();

    std::chrono::duration<double>   diff = trigger.get() - startTime;

    std::cout << "Duration = " << diff.count() << " secs." << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

clock() call will not filter out executions of different processes and threads run by scheduler in parallel with program event handler thread. There are alternative like times() and getrusage() which tells cpu time of process. Though it is not clearly mentioned about thread behaviour for these calls but if it is Linux, threads are treated as processes but it has to be investigated.

Answer (score 0):

`clock()` is the wrong tool here, because it does not count the time actually required by the CPU to run your operation, for example, if the thread is not running at all, the time is still counted.

Instead you have to use platform-specific APIs, such as `pthread_getcpuclockid` for POSIX-compliant systems (Check if `_POSIX_THREAD_CPUTIME` is defined), that counts the actual time spent by a specific thread.

You can take a look at a [benchmarking library](https://github.com/dtrugman/benchmark) I wrote for C++ that supports thread-aware measuring (see `struct thread_clock` implementation).

Or, you can use the code snippet from the [man page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/pthread_getcpuclockid.3.html):

```
/* Link with "-lrt" */

#include <time.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <errno.h>

#define handle_error(msg) \
        do { perror(msg); exit(EXIT_FAILURE); } while (0)

#define handle_error_en(en, msg) \
        do { errno = en; perror(msg); exit(EXIT_FAILURE); } while (0)

static void *
thread_start(void *arg)
{
    printf("Subthread starting infinite loop\n");
    for (;;)
        continue;
}

static void
pclock(char *msg, clockid_t cid)
{
    struct timespec ts;
    printf("%s", msg);
    if (clock_gettime(cid, &ts) == -1)
        handle_error("clock_gettime");
    printf("%4ld.%03ld\n", ts.tv_sec, ts.tv_nsec / 1000000);
}

int
main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    pthread_t thread;
    clockid_t cid;
    int j, s;

    s = pthread_create(&thread, NULL, thread_start, NULL);
    if (s != 0)
        handle_error_en(s, "pthread_create");

    printf("Main thread sleeping\n");
    sleep(1);

    printf("Main thread consuming some CPU time...\n");
    for (j = 0; j < 2000000; j++)
        getppid();

    pclock("Process total CPU time: ", CLOCK_PROCESS_CPUTIME_ID);

    s = pthread_getcpuclockid(pthread_self(), &cid);
    if (s != 0)
        handle_error_en(s, "pthread_getcpuclockid");

    pclock("Main thread CPU time:   ", cid);

    /* The preceding 4 lines of code could have been replaced by:
    pclock("Main thread CPU time:   ", CLOCK_THREAD_CPUTIME_ID); */

    s = pthread_getcpuclockid(thread, &cid);
    if (s != 0)
        handle_error_en(s, "pthread_getcpuclockid");
    pclock("Subthread CPU time: 1    ", cid);

    exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);         /* Terminates both threads */
}
```